# How to remove axis tick marks when there isn't a corresponding value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

When plotting data with the x-axis as a date and the y-axis using matplotlib, there is a problem that the chart is drawn with space on the date with no value as in the graph below. I hope the 24th and 25th are not on the x-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
s.index = pd.Index([20210419, 20210420, 20210421, 20210422, 20210423, 20210426, 20210427, 20210428, 20210429, 20210430])
plt.bar(s.index, s)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- The best option is probably to use `pandas.Series.plot`, because no extra imports, and no extra formatting is required.
- Using `seaborn` is the next best option, but requires importing the package.
- Using `matplotlib` directly and casting the axis as a string is my least favorite option.

### Plot with `pandas.Series.plot`

- This also does not require the axis to be cast as a string
- Example with `pandas v1.2.4`

```py
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
s.index = pd.Index([20210419, 20210420, 20210421, 20210422, 20210423, 20210426, 20210427, 20210428, 20210429, 20210430])
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index, format='%Y%m%d').date

s.plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### Plot with `seaborn`

- Use `seaborn`, which is a high-level API for `matplotlib`
- In this case, `.date` is used to extract only the date component of the datetime, otherwise time will be included in the x-axis tick labels.
- Casting the axis values as a string is not required for a `seaborn.barplot`, but would be required for other types of seaborn plots.
- Example with `seaborn v0.11.1`

```py
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
s.index = pd.Index([20210419, 20210420, 20210421, 20210422, 20210423, 20210426, 20210427, 20210428, 20210429, 20210430])
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index, format='%Y%m%d').date

sns.barplot(x=s.index, y=s)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### Plot with `matplotlib`

- The issue is when plotting numbers or dates, the matplotlib API includes the ordinal axis labels, even when there isn't a corresponding axis value.
- One resolution is to cast the `Series` that is the x-axis, as a `str`
- This solution applies when plotting against either axis and for plot types other than `bar`.
- Example with `matplotlib v3.3.4`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
s.index = pd.Index([20210419, 20210420, 20210421, 20210422, 20210423, 20210426, 20210427, 20210428, 20210429, 20210430])

# format to a correct datetime format and then convert to a string
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index, format='%Y%m%d')

plt.bar(s.index.astype('str'), s)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]